# How to get data from thymeleaf form to the controller before submitting?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working in a project with spring boot & thymeleaf.

I have a form in Thymeleaf where I get some info to create something like a booking.
The info I request on the form is CheckIn,CheckOut, Method of payment and Price.
Before I save the booking I need to let the client know how much it is going to cost.
To calculate that I need to know the days they are going to book.
Here is my question. How can I renderize the price once they choose the date of checkin and checkout?
I already know how to get the days between and so on...
Before the client hit on submit I need to renderize the price.

Everything is working fine submiting the form & saving it into the database.

This is the form the client is showed.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdb1s.png

This is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/bookings/{userId}/new")
public String createBookingForm(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, Model model) {
    Booking booking = new Booking();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
    model.addAttribute("booking", booking);
    return "bookings-create";
}

@PostMapping("/bookings/{userId}")
public String createBooking(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
                            @ModelAttribute("booking") BookingDto bookingDto,
                            BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("booking", bookingDto);
        return "bookings/create";
    }
    bookingService.createBooking(userId, bookingDto);
    return "redirect:/users/" + userId;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<form role="form" method="post" th:action="@{/bookings/{userId}(userId=${userId})}" th:object="${booking}">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="startTime">Checkin</label>
                    <input
                            type="datetime-local"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="startTime"
                            name="startTime"
                            th:field="*{startTime}"
                            placeholder="Checkin">
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('startTime')}" class="text-danger" th:errors="*{startTime}"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="endTime">Checkout</label>
                    <input
                            type="datetime-local"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="endTime"
                            name="endTime"
                            th:field="*{endTime}"
                            placeholder="Checkout">
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('endTime')}" class="text-danger" th:errors="*{endTime}"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Method Of Payment</label>
                    <select th:field="*{methodOfPayment}" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected th:value="${'Efectivo'}">Efectivo</option>
                        <option th:value="${'Tarjeta de Débito'}">Tarjeta de Débito</option>
                        <option th:value="${'Tarjeta de Crédito'}">Tarjeta de Crédito</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="price">Price</label>
                        <input
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                id="price"
                                name="price"
                                th:field="*{price}"
                                placeholder="price">
                        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('price')}" class="text-danger" th:errors="*{price}"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col mt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Get price</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```